# Using Shadow DOM within ContentEditable to create protected blocks of text

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, web-component, shadow-dom

Recently I've been developing a simple editor using ContentEditable. The requirements for the application are simple, with the one exception of being able to insert blocks of text which are protected from the normal editing actions.

These blocks of text cannot be edited and must behave as a single character for the purposes of moving the cursor through them or deleting them.

An example of the resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable style="height: 400px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 4px; padding: 4px; overflow:auto;">
  "This is standard text with a "
    <span class="attrib">
      #shadow-root
        "PROTECTED"
      "_"
    </span>
  " block"
</div>
```

Whilst this provides the protected section of text I need, it has a couple of major problems that I cannot resolve:

- The text after the shadow DOM element does not display.
- The cursor does not move through the shadowDOM element at all.

Is there a better way to do this or is it just not possible to use the shadow DOM in this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can force the `contenteditable` attribute to `false` in your protected element:

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 4px; padding: 4px; overflow:auto;">
  "This is standard text with a 
  <span contenteditable="false">PROTECTED</span> 
   block"
</div>
```

**Solution 2**

If you want to use Shadow DOM without `contenteditable=false`:

You can observe the caret position using `window.getSelection().anchorOffset`, and check if the position have changed.

If not, you'll have to move the caret to the next text node (if possible) with [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)'s `setBaseAndExtent()`.

Here is a minimal example which works when the `[Right Arrow]` key is pressed:

```js
editor.querySelector( '.attrib' )
      .attachShadow({mode: 'open' } )
      .innerHTML = 'PROTECTED'
   
editor.addEventListener( 'keydown', onkeydown )

var position = 0 

function onkeydown( ev )
{
  if ( ev.key == "ArrowRight" )
  {
    setTimeout( function ()
    { 
      var sel = window.getSelection()
      if ( position == sel.anchorOffset )
      {
        var anchor = sel.anchorNode 
        if ( anchor.nextSibling && anchor.nextSibling.nextSibling )
        {
          console.warn( 'move next' ) 
          var next = anchor.nextSibling.nextSibling
          sel.setBaseAndExtent( next, 1, next, 1)
        }
      } 
      position = sel.anchorOffset
    } ) 
  }
}
```

```css
.attrib {
    background: lightblue ;
}
  
#editor {
    height: 100px; width:400px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 4px; padding: 4px; overflow:auto
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable>"This 
  is standard text with a <span class="attrib">TEST</span> block"
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. My first attempt was with contenteditable="false", but I found a few issues with that approach too, especially when the protected section appears at the end of the text (strange cursor behaviour) or selecting text for copying. Some browsers are worse than others, although I have to admit contenteditable has less problems than using shadow DOM so far. I suppose I was just hoping to find a more reliable solution that required less working around issues.

Comment: @Jason I've updated my answer to work with Shadow DOM but as you noticed yourself it requires more work to handle all limit cases.

Comment: Thanks @Supersharp. It might prevent some of the issues I'm having with contenteditable so I'll try out something along those lines.